# Как вызвать DialogFragment с параметрами?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Я произвожу вызов `DialogFragment` через;

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

Как, при вызове, мне передать в `DialogFragment` строки `strToDialog_1` и `strToDialog_2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно также как и с обычными фрагментами - через `Bundle`:

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("key", "value");
myDialog .setArguments(args);
myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

И в `onCreate()` фрагмента данные вытаскиваем:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    String value=args.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: Я сделал все как написано, но теперь у меня диалог вообще перестал появляться и только срабатывает метод `onDismiss` , как вы думаете почему это может быть?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Т.е. вы добавили аргументы в диалог и он перестал открываться?.. 0_о

Comment: у меня сначала все работало без аргументов, а потом когда я сделал все так как написано у вас, то перестало работать... Опять все убрал и опять заработало...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, и в логах пусто?.. Попробуйте, что ли, вопрос задать...